# BeautifulSoup Soup Recursive

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I would like to retrieve the url's of a web page recursively and get the result in a list.

This is the code I'm using:

```
catalog_url = "http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov:9090/dods/gfs_0p25/"

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup #  conda install -c asmeurer beautiful-soup=4.3.2 
import urllib2
from datetime import datetime

html_page = urllib2.urlopen(catalog_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)

urls_day = []
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    if datetime.today().strftime('%Y') in link.get('href'): # String contains today's year in name
        print link.get('href')
        urls_day.append(link.get('href'))

urls_final = []
for run in urls_day:
    html_page2 = urllib2.urlopen(run)
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(html_page2)
    for links in soup2.findAll('a'):
        if datetime.today().strftime('%Y') in soup2.get('a'):
            print links.get('href')
            urls_final.append(links.get('href'))
```

In the first loop I get the url's in the `catalog_url`. `urls_day` is a list object with the url's that contain the string of the current year in it.

The second loop fails with the following output:

```
<a href="http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov:9090/dods">GrADS Data Server</a>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in <module>
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

`urls_final` should be the list object containing the url's of my interest.

Any idea of how to solve it? I've checked similar posts of beautiful soup with recursion, but I always get the same 'NoneType' response.

Comment: You probably need `if datetime.today().strftime('%Y') in soup2.findAll('a'):` instead of `…soup2.get('a')`.

Comment: Anyway, it will not work. string like `Oct 24 04:42 UTC` is not part of any <a> tag, it's just a text before <a> tag. You have to locate this text and then locate the tag after it.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the returned value is a NoneType before calling the recursive function. I wrote an example which you can improve upon.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime
import urllib2

CATALOG_URL = "http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov:9090/dods/gfs_0p25/"

today = datetime.today().strftime('%Y')

cache = {}


def cached(func):
    def wraps(url):
        if url not in cache:
            cache[url] = True
            return func(url)
    return wraps


@cached
def links_from_url(url):
    html_page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "lxml")
    s = set([link.get('href') for link in soup.findAll('a') if today in link.get('href')])
    return s if len(s) else url


def crawl(links):
    if not links:  # Checking for NoneType
        return
    if type(links) is str:
        return links
    if len(links) > 1:
        return [crawl(links_from_url(link)) for link in links]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    crawl(links_from_url(CATALOG_URL))
    print cache.keys()
```

Comment: I'm afraid this will not solve OP's problem. And I'm not sure about your `cached` decorator: it returns nothing if `url` is cached: is it intentionally?